# Задача на Python N^3 = N1^3 + N2^3 + N3^3

Tags: python

Всем доброго дня, требуется реализовать следующую Задачу двумя способами:
Найти наименьшее натуральное число N такое, что N^3 = N1^3 + N2^3 + N3^3, при этом
N1≠N2≠N3.
С первым способом трудностей нет, написал через фор, со вторым возникли проблемы. Хотел писать через Вайл, но все никак не выходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Удачный вариант с for:

```
check = set()
for a in range(1,10):
    for b in range(1, 10):
        for c in range(1, 10):
            for d in range(1, 10):
                if (b != c and c != d and b != d):
                    if (a ** 3 == ((b ** 3) + (c ** 3) + (d ** 3))):
                        check.add(a)
print(min(check))
```

Неудачный вариант с while:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
while a < 10:
    a+=1
    while b < 10:
        b+=1
        while c < 10:
            c+=1
            while d < 10:
                d+=1
                if (b != c and c != d and b != d):
                    if (a ** 3 == ((b ** 3) + (c ** 3) + (d ** 3))):
                        print(a)
```

Comment: Так бы и написали не помогите, а сделайте за меня. Где ваши попытки и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: как и говорил, пробовал сделатьчерез вайл: a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
while a < 10:
    a+=1
    while b < 10:
        b+=1
        while c < 10:
            c+=1
            while d < 10:
                d+=1
                if (b != c and c != d and b != d):
                    if (a ** 3 == ((b ** 3) + (c ** 3) + (d ** 3))):
                        print(a)

Comment: @АлександрЕгоров тогда лучше добавьте вашу попытку в вопрос. А то выглядит, что вы ничего не делали, просто хотите, что бы за вас решили. В идеале оба варианта, что бы в ответе просто не повторили то что вы уже сделали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста :)

```
n = 1
n1 = 1
n2 = 1
n3 = 1

while(n > 0):
    while(n1 < 100):
        while(n2 < 100):
            while(n3 < 100):
                if n1 != n2 and n1 != n3:
                    if n**3 == n1**3 + n2**3 + n3**3:
                        print(n, n1, n2, n3)
                n3+=1
            n2+=1
            n3 = 1
        n1+=1
        n2 = 1
    n+=1
    n1 = 1
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное